# the default android browser doesnt work with this javascript function

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cross-browser

I have a problem with this code:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
   evt.stopPropagation();
   evt.preventDefault(); // stop default

   console.log('ejecutado handleFileSelects')

   var divOrigen = evt.target.parentNode; //get the div of the input
   var divDestino = $(divOrigen).find('img'); //get the div for preview the img
   var inputDestino = $(divOrigen).find('input[type="file"]'); // the input file 
   var files = evt.target.files; //get files in array

   if (files.length) {
      for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
         if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
         }
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
               $(divDestino).attr('src', e.target.result); //read files content to preview in div
            };
         })(f);
         reader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
      $(inputDestino).popover('destroy');
   } else {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      evt.preventDefault();
      $(inputDestino).popover('show');
      console.log('files is empty');
      $(divDestino).attr('src', '/images/index/publicacion/dragAndDropHere.png');
   }
}
```

This code changes the background of a `div`. The purpose of the `div` is to preview the image of the input file. In Opera, Firefox, Internet Explorer and Safari it works fine, but when I try it on my Android tablet, nothing happens. Is there a tool similar to Firebug for Android? Or any framework that I can use for Android tablets?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the first / from the image source, so instead of

```
$(divDestino).attr('src', '/images/index/publicacion/dragAndDropHere.png');
```

you have

```
$(divDestino).attr('src', 'images/index/publicacion/dragAndDropHere.png');
```

Comment: dragAndDropHere.png is an image that appears by default in the div indicating the zone to drop the image ... this is not the error...